# ColdFusion 10 ORM (Hibernate) Date Evaluation

Tags: hibernate, datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm having a difficult time understanding why the following HQL isn't working with my data...

```
ormExecuteQuery('from Campaign where StartDate < ? and EndDate > ?', [utcNow(), utcNow()])
```

Sample of my data looks like...

```
StartDate              EndDate
2013-10-06 22:15:00.0  2013-12-31 23:15:00.0
```

Dump of my utcNow() function return is `{ts '2013-10-06 23:14:15'}`, so I'm fairly certain my system is calculating UTC correctly.

Now, if I remove the StartDate portion of the query it works fine and respects the EndDate but it does not work with the StartDate in any fashion.

Comment: If you change the start date in the db to be completely outside any possible DST/timezone issues (i.e. subtract a day) does it work?

Comment: What happens if you change the query to use `OR` instead of `AND`. Maybe it is a logic issue instead of a data issue.